# Creating a tree based on constraints

Tags: constraints, graph-theory

I would appreciate any help with problem bellow. Even a direction of what I should read about. Thank you!

I need to create a a graph (tree) given a set of rules which indicates the relationship between vertices, where the relationship does not have to be direct.

Constraints:

- Vertex rules should be met. In the example bellow, A<-D indicates that A is the parent of D, though it doesn't have to be a direct parent.
- The distance between vertices should be as low as possible.
- Each vertex can only have one parent, therefore the outcome will be a tree.

Example set of rules: [A<-D, D<-E, E<-F, A<-B, B<-C, E<-C, F<-C]

First image is a possible outcome, but it is not the best one given the distance between vertex C to F and C to E is too far. Therefore a better solution is the 2nd image.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It seems that the graph edges must be undirected ( otherwise the first diagram is NOT a possible outcome because you cannot travel from F to C ) .  But in an undirected graph the constraint "Each vertex can only have one parent" is meaningless.  There is something wrong with your problem specification.

Comment: Something like this: 1.  An undirected graph. 2. Each node has at most two edges. 3 Rules specify some node pairs.  4. The distance between specified node pairs must be minimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the rules:

1. The distance between vertices should be as low as possible; and
2. Each vertex can only have one parent.

and the syntax:

3. `A<-D` indicates that `A` is an ancestor of `D`.

*(Note: the change of terminology to ancestor.)*

Then for the graph generated by `A<-D, D<-E, E<-F, A<-B, B<-C, E<-C, F<-C`

This gives 3 paths from `A` to `C` (using the syntax `(X -> Y)` as `X` is the [direct] parent of `Y`):

- `(A -> D), (D -> E), (E -> C)` and
- `(A -> D), (D -> E), (E -> F), (F -> C)` and
- `(A -> B), (B -> C)`

However, by the 2nd rule ("Each vertex can only have one parent") then there must only be a single path from `A` to `C` which passes through `D, E, F` (in that order) and also through `B` so the possible paths have the order `A,D,E,F,C` with `B` inserted somewhere:

- Path 1: `(A -> B), (B -> D), (D -> E), (E -> F), (F -> C)`
- Path 2: `(A -> D), (D -> B), (B -> E), (E -> F), (F -> C)`
- Path 3: `(A -> D), (D -> E), (E -> B), (B -> F), (F -> C)`
- Path 4: `(A -> D), (D -> E), (E -> F), (F -> B), (B -> C)`

You can then calculate the distances for each of the rules (assuming a constant distance between each vertex):

| Rule | Path1 | Path2 | Path3 | Path4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `A<-D` | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| `D<-E` | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| `E<-F` | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| `A<-B` | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| `B<-C` | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| `E<-C` | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| `F<-C` | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| Total | 12 | 12 | 12 | 12 |

Since the total distance for all the paths is identical then any/all of the four solutions is equally valid against your rules.